# Building Electron with my own module

Tags: node.js, npm, electron-builder

I am learning building Node modules and packaging it with Electron. I've successfully built an module out of a CPP file and can run it with node. However, to run it with Electron I need to rebuild Electron. There are instructions out there, for example:

1. https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.37.2/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules.md#using-native-node-modules
2. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2330

Here I have an `addon.node` file after running `node-gyp build`. I can reference it in the node application from anywhere: `var addon = require('.Release\addon');` and it works fine. However, when I build Electron with it I don't understand where to put the `.node` file so that it is used in the build. Before I run `node_modules\.bin\electron-rebuild` (see bullet point 1 link above) where should I put the `addon.node` file? Is it right to say that before I even test it withing Electron (with `console.log` or something) I need to run `electron-rebuild`. Is there a step that I missing that I need to take from having the `addon.node` file to starting to build it into Electron?

Thank you.